# How do I add new articles with transactional replication?

Tags: sql-server-2000, replication, transactional-replication

Suppose I'm using transactional replication to replicate articles from one server to another (**both running SQL Server 2000**). This is setup and working great.

Then, I decide to add a new article. First, I add it to the publication via `Publication Properties > Articles > Objects to Publish`.

Then, what do I do?

It'd be nice if I could have the new article replicate without having to generate a new snapshot from scratch...and then wipe out the subscriber and rebuild it from scratch. That's an awful lot of work for just adding 1 table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate a new snapshot, but only the changes will be replicated. See:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34098797/adding-new-table-to-publi.aspx

Comment: Do you know if this applies to *transactional* replication, too? I'll test it tomorrow to see...

Comment: Yes, it also applies to transactional replication, there are some more details here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/b972a1be-045d-4c99-94c6-388f6b92bb38